# Comparing run times of algorithms

Tags: time-complexity

I have two algorithms with time complexities of O(n log n) and O(n log3 n).

Which of these algorithms is more efficient? for example this case, as they seem so close? Or am I right in thinking that in terms of complexity they are equal as they are the same rate of growth?

Comment: O(n log n) and O(n log3 n) are the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O(n log n) and O(n log3 n) are **the same thing**.

Comment: So the problems i have are 2T(n/2) + O(n) and 3T(n/3) + n , which gave me both O(n log n) and O(n log3 n).. so they are equal in terms of big O?

Comment: @Lunar: I'm too tired to figure out the recursions, so I can't tell you whether you derived the correct time complexities...

Comment: @Lunar By the master theorem, both are `O(nlogn)`.